# FluentNhibernate Mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This is my entity-relationship diagram

```
http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/privadas/1605595base.png
```

Scenario :These are my classes simplified

```
public class plaserv
{
public plaserv()
{
    plamoviles = new List<plamoviles>();
    asistencia = new List<asistencia>();
    plaattach = new List<plaattach>();
}
public virtual double id_planilla { get; private set; }
public virtual double id_parte { get; set; }
...
public virtual int id_tservicio { get; set; }
public virtual int id_legacar { get; set; }
...
public virtual personal personal { get; set; }
public virtual IList<plamoviles> plamoviles { get; private set; }
public virtual plaparte plaparte { get; set; }
public virtual IList<asistencia> asistencia { get; private set; }
public virtual IList<plaattach> plaattach { get; private set; }
}

public class plaparte
{
    public virtual double id_planilla { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class plamoviles
{
    public plamoviles()
    {
        plamoviles_combustible = new List<combustible>();
        plamoviles_moviles = new List<movil>();
    }

    public virtual double id { get; private set; }
    public virtual double id_planilla { get; set; }
    public virtual int nmovil { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal cant_combustible { get; set; }
    public virtual int id_tcombustible { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<combustible> plamoviles_combustible { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<movil> plamoviles_moviles { get; private set; }
}

public class plaattach
{
    public virtual double id { get; set; }
    public virtual double id_planilla { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] archivo { get; set; }
}

public class personal
{
    public personal()
    {
        personal_jerarquia = new List<jerarquia>().OrderBy(x => x.posicion).ToList();
    }

    public virtual double id_legajo { get; set; }
    public virtual string nomyape { get; set; }
    public virtual int id_jerar { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual IList<jerarquia> personal_jerarquia { get; private set; }
}
   .....
```

These are my mapping

```
    public class plaservMap : ClassMap<plaserv>
{
    public plaservMap()
    {
        Table("plaserv");

        Id(x => x.id_planilla);
        Map(x => x.autor_llamada).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.tipo_llamada).Length(3).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.direccion).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.hora_aviso).Length(5).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.hora_salida).Length(5).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.hora_regreso).Length(5);
        Map(x => x.fecha);
        Map(x => x.fecha_regreso);
        Map(x => x.cant_moviles);
        Map(x => x.cant_perso);
        Map(x => x.id_legacar);

        References(x => x.personal); //muchos a uno
        HasMany(x => x.plamoviles).Inverse().Cascade.All();
        HasMany(x => x.plaattach).Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

It is properly to use

```
References(x => x.personal)
```

I should add to the class personal to close the relationship between personal with plaserv?
I should add something like in personal

```
HasMany(x => x.plaserv).Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

Comment: Could you repost your image. It is too small to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to implement through Automap